# Pycharm OpenCV Can't Access Camera

Tags: camera

My built-in camera suddenly couldn't be accessed after I installed and executed opencv code on pycharm. I had reseted and deleted pycharm but it was not worked. In device manage i can't find camera drive(but sometime i find it and my camera work properly). I have Matlab on my laptop too I think maybe there are some conflict between apps. Hope someone can help me, thank you guys.

Comment: Maybe you can try your camera on another computer. and try your computer with another camera.  Make sure your system is stable for your camera.

Comment: If you reboot your computer, is the problem solved ? if not you can try above comment.